# Trouble loading leaflet tilelayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm using leaflet.js and adding a Fulcrum Mapbox tile layer URL to load a specific map into my website... The tiles load in circles and I'm not sure whats going on! Any help would be awesome.

Image of the resulting tiles:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
 var backgroundLayer = L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/measure/ck8515ktb01vd1ilngup1r6rr/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWVhc3VyZSIsImEiOiJjanV6dW00NjIxY3liNDNwZnc4eWozbjY0In0.zj7VWavAGgdjQpOwWoXDqA",{
            minZoom: 2,
            maxNativeZoom: 22,
            maxZoom: 22,
        });

        var map = L.map("mymap");

        map.setView([35, -95], 14);

        map.addLayer(backgroundLayer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as expected. Maybe there is a conflict with a css from some other library you use or there is an error somewhere else in your code.
Here is how it should be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>



</head>

<body>



  <div id="mymap" style="width: 600px; height: 100vh;"></div>
  <script>
    var backgroundLayer = L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/measure/ck8515ktb01vd1ilngup1r6rr/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWVhc3VyZSIsImEiOiJjanV6dW00NjIxY3liNDNwZnc4eWozbjY0In0.zj7VWavAGgdjQpOwWoXDqA", {
      minZoom: 2,
      maxNativeZoom: 22,
      maxZoom: 22,
    });

    var map = L.map("mymap");

    map.setView([35, -95], 9);

    map.addLayer(backgroundLayer);
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Definitely CSS.   Look for something like `img { border-radius: 50% }`